# BrowserStack - Node.js concurrent testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I've been looking at ways to create a reasonable structure for scalable testing in Node.js using BrowserStack specifically.

Please view the source here:

```
https://gist.github.com/Palgie/10886008
```

I'm getting an issue when trying to close sessions or quit the driver so when running concurrent tests it will frequently tell me that my max sessions are in use (see below).

It feels like a race condition but it could be something blindingly obvious.

```
  Now testing Chrome - 22.0
  Now testing IE - 10.0
  ․․․․
  Stopping test
  Stopping test
  ․

    4 passing (14s)
    1 failing

    1)  "after all" hook:
       Error: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
        at checkHasNotQuit (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:291:13)
        at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:263:3)
        at webdriver.WebDriver.quit (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:331:21)
        at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/driver.js:35:14)
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1598:20)
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1463:8)
        at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
    ==== async task ====
        at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/testing/index.js:126:14)
        at Hook.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:196:15)
        at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:259:10)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:271:7
        at done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:185:5)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:199:9
        at /Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/testing/index.js:92:5
        at /Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1178:15
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1598:20)
        at notify (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:428:12)
        at notifyAll (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:397:7)
        at resolve (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:375:7)
        at fulfill (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:493:5)
        at /Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1465:10
        at Object.webdriver.promise.asap (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:732:5)
        at newFrame.then.e (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1614:25)
        at /Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1178:15
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1598:20)
        at notify (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:428:12)
        at notifyAll (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:397:7)
        at resolve (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:375:7)
        at fulfill (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:493:5)
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.resolveFrame_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1519:9)
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.getNextTask_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1488:12)
        at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/Users/gourleyp/Sites/bs-webdriver/node_modules/browserstack-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1446:59)
        at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:252:14)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

In the source I reference which as far as I understand it should execute the session but it doesn't feel like it s.

```
test.after(function() {
  console.log('Stopping test');
  driver.quit();
});
```

As far as I understand it after all the mocha tests or webdriver tests in that browser run then it will terminate driver and it'll then initialise a new instance in the before method.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can use selenium-runner to run tests in parallel. A sample of using selenium-runner to run tests in parallel on BrowserStack is given in following documentation : https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node.

Further if selenium-runner doesn't satisfy your need, can you please share your needs (which specific framework or library code u want to run in parallel) so that we can look onto the issue

Akshay @
BrowserStack